# Featured Image or Post Thumbnail Displaying on index.php?

Tags: images, loop

When I'm on the main page, of my site, `site.com` it shows an excerpt of each post along with a category to the side.  it also displays the same thumbnail image but above the content and I'm guessing because its grabbing the first image in the post.. I already tried removing `<?php the_post_thumbnail();?>` from the single.php and it didnt help.

How do I stop any additional images from displaying on the homepage?

Comment: do you use a static page as your homepage? either way, please post the code that displays your main page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

WordPress will never use `single.php` to render the site front page. Refer to [the Template Hierarchy for Site Front Page](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy#Front_Page_display):

- `front-page.php`
- Static page hierarchy: `$custom-template.php`, `page-$slug.php`, `page.php`
- Blog posts index hierarchy: `home.php`
- `index.php`

Ensure that you are calling `body_class()` inside of the HTML `<body>` tag, and provide a live link to your site, and we can provide a more specific answer regarding which file to edit.